# Don't understand why I keep getting 'can't assign to operator' error

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm learning by doing a practice assignment that looks through a list of numbers and ignores the numbers that occur between a 6 and 9, including the 6 and 9. It then returns the sum of every other number.

While making the program, I get a 'can't assign to operator' error. I've tried to read similar answers but I don't quite understand why I keep getting the error.

```
arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
flag1 = True
flag2 = True
total = 0
for num in arr:
    while num != 6:
        flag1 = True and flag2 = True
    while flag1 == True and flag2 == True:
        total = total + num
        break
    if num == 6:
        flag1 = True and flag2 = False
    while flag1 == True and flag2 == False:
        total = total + 0
        break
    if num == 9:
        flag1 = True and flag2 = True
print(total)
```

The error occurs at line 7 which and it says:

```
    flag1 = True and flag2 = True
           ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: You can't join assignments using `and`. What you are exactly trying to achieve? Also you will get stuck in an endless loop in the first `while` if the `num` is `6`.

Comment: `flag1, flag2 = True, True`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Or `flag1 = flag2 = True`, but the rest of the code doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: yep, much simpler

Comment: Being simple statements, you could also just write `flag1 = True; flag2 = True`. But for readability, you should just put each assignment on a separate line, as you did prior to the loop.

Comment: Note: Even after this is fixed, you never modify `num` in that first `while` loop, so if `num` isn't `6`, that loop is infinite. Basically everything about this code is broken, but that's the first thing that'll break once you fix the clearly invalid syntax.

Comment: @Selcuk Right, I should add a break

Comment: @chepner  good idea, I'll split it like that

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre].

Comment: I get invalid syntax error for 'while flag1==True, flag2==True:'

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt, correct, that isn't valid syntax. Do you have a question? (If you want to combine the two statements, use an `and` or `or` clause, not a comma).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm trying to make a statement that says 'while flag1 is true and flag2 is true, do the following:' but I tried to use "while flag1 = True and flag2 = True:" that didn't work, then someone in the comments suggested using a semi-colon, so I tried "while flag1=True; flag2;True:" but that didn't work either.

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt: You need to run through a proper Python tutorial/class; trying to do exercises by guessing at syntax until something works by accident is not a practical approach here.

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt, `var = value` is not a test for whether "var is value" is true, it's a statement "modify var to contain value". If you want a test, you need `==`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `flag1 = True and flag2 = True` doesn't mean "assign to `flag1`, then assign to `flag2`". It's parsed as

```
 flag1 = (True and flag2) = True
```

which is a chained assignment which attempts to assign `True` to both `flag1` and the expression `True and flag2`. You can't assign to this particular expression:

```
>>> True and flag2 = True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Because both assignments are simple statements (according to the Python grammar), you *can* join the two on one line using a semi-colon

```
flag1 = True; flag2 = True
```

or you can use tuple unpacking

```
flag1, flag2 = True, True
```

However, the most readable option is to simply put both assignments on separate lines.

```
flag1 = True
flag2 = True
```

Comment: What about trying to make a while statement to ensure flag1 and flag2 are true? I tried to write 'while flag1==True; flag2==True:' but I got a syntax error

Comment: Those aren't assignments; `while flag1 == True and flag2 == True` is perfectly valid, because `flag1 == True and flag2 == True` is a Boolean expression (though it is more idiomatically written `while flag1 and flag2:`; there's rarely a reason to involve Boolean literals in a comparison).